# How can a bijection from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ exist when a non square matrix is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I have found references online that say there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I have also found references that say that if a bijection exists between sets, then an inverse exists. However, I know that any matrix transformation, $A$, between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ which is not square and thus does not have an inverse.

How is this not a contradiction on the various claims? Thank you for the help in clearing this up.

Comment: Not every map is a linear map.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos there is a recent (not so matured) discussion on the tag "functions" [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/how-to-discourage-users-from-using-the-functions-tag) (Of course, you are very welcome to join that discussion!)

Comment: @JohnMa In my opinion, that tag is appropriate for questions concerning injective functions, surjective functions and the existence of an inverse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help you to know what sort of bijection it actually is. Here's an example, if you think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as just a list of n numbers, then take the n numbers and interleave their digits to form a single number. For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

(3.45, 27.9, 0.045) -> 20370.490504005

Now it's fairly clearly that this is a bijection, and fairly clear you can invert it. But you can't represent it with a matrix, because it's not at all a linear mapping.

Answer (score 3):

There is no contradiction. *Every* bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb R$ has an inverse, whereas (if $n>1$) there is no *linear* bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb R$.